# Error message: Could not access the directory

Tags: files-and-directories

I ran multiple Mathematica files using the the NoteBookOpen/NoteboookEvaluate options. Now once the run is over, I am not able to save the files. I get the error message - "Could not access the directory. You should check the directory's permission."

Would be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Can you share your code? Are you sure you have permission to write to the directory you intend to write to?

Comment: Thanks. This is the code for first file. I had multiple similar files running.      File1 = NotebookOpen[ "C:/....."];
SelectionMove[File1, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[File1]

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1803715).